# MVC Update-database, Enable-Migrations problems after upgrading to EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have upgraded to EF6 in my MVC application.

When I try `Enable-Migrations` in the PM console.

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Cardsender02'

I have only one project in the solution and as I see it I do have a context.

```
namespace Cardsender02.Models
{
    public class CardContext : DbContext
    {
        public CardContext()
           : base("DefaultConnection")
        {}
```

Then I try

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Cardsender02.Models.CardContext
```

But that gives me

> The type 'Cardsender02.Migrations.Configuration' does not inherit from
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations
>   configuration types must extend from
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.

What to do now?

Configuration class:

```
namespace Cardsender02.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Cardsender02.Models.CardContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Cardsender02.Models.CardContext context)
    {}
 }}
```

Comment: You need a class that inherits from `DbMigrationsConfiguration` to go along side your context.

Comment: I can't read that, please update your question when adding code :)

Comment: @ThorOstergaard, [click this link](http://i.imgur.com/dHJ69Qx.png?1?4032). and in what project is `CardContext` located ?

Comment: CardContext is located in the only project in the solution - CardSender02

Comment: try `Enable-Migrations -verbose` and see if there is any useful information

Comment: Don't think so:

Using StartUp project 'Cardsender02'.
Using NuGet project 'Cardsender02'.
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: No context type was found in the assembly 'Cardsender02'.
 at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeFinder.FindType()

Comment: try to reinstall the entity framework, probably it's not installed properly when you upgrade it. Execute this command on PMC `Update-Package -reinstall EntityFramework`

Comment: I think my problem is that I need to upgrade all my code to EF6 - working on that...

Comment: Have downgraded to EF4.3 and now the update-database works as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade to EF6, please make sure all dependencies are properly upgraded including the assembly, config, and other references.

You can use this command to reinstall properly from Package Manager Console.

```
Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
```